# Binary mask with shift operation without cycle

Tags: python, math, binary, logical-operators

We have some large binary number N (large means millions of digits). We also have binary mask M where 1 means that we must remove digit in this position in number N and move all higher bits one position right.

Example:

```
N = 100011101110
M = 000010001000
Res   1000110110
```

Is it possible to solve this problem without cycle with some set of logical or arithmetical operations? We can assume that we have access to bignum arithmetic in Python.

Feels like it should be something like this:
Res = N - (N xor M)
But it doesn't work

**UPD**: My current solution with cycle is following:

```
def prepare_reduced_arrays(dict_of_N, mask):
    '''
    mask: string '0000011000'
    each element of dict_of_N - big python integer
    '''

    capacity = len(mask)
    answer = dict()
    for el in dict_of_N:
        answer[el] = 0

    new_capacity = 0
    for i in range(capacity - 1, -1, -1):
        if mask[i] == '1':
            continue
        cap2 = (1 << new_capacity)
        pos = (capacity - i - 1)
        for el in dict_of_N:
            current_bit = (dict_of_N[el] >> pos) & 1
            if current_bit:
                answer[el] |= cap2
        new_capacity += 1

    return answer, new_capacity
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean with *shift one position right*?

Comment: Do you want to let the "bits" collapse (in the sense that they are removed and the higher bit takes that position)?

Comment: Exactly. I need bit to be removed from given positions.

Comment: I'm quite sure you cannot do this without loops (well perhaps with for instance 64 operations, but this is simply *unrolling* the array).

Comment: Have been thinking for half an hour now, nice question. I also don't see how you can do it just with arithmetic and logic operations. It feels like you need as many arithmetic operations as there are 1s in you mask, and you can't simplify them because there is no known pattern for the mask.

Comment: I love this question, but I agree with @Andrei that loops are required.  However, as seen in my answer, there exists an efficient way to achieve your result.

Comment: If we had something like the [`PEXT` instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXT.html), this would be straightforward.

Comment: Depending on how big these numbers are, you may actually get best performance from explicit manipulation of a sequence of bits, rather than a bignum.

Answer (score 4):

While this may not be possible without a loop in python, it can be made extremely fast with `numba` and just in time compilation. I went on the assumption that your inputs could be easily represented as boolean arrays, which would be very simple to construct from a binary file using `struct`. The method I have implemented involves iterating a few different objects, however these iterations were chosen carefully to make sure they were compiler optimized, and never doing the same work twice. The first iteration is using `np.where` to locate the indices of all the bits to delete. This specific function (among many others) is optimized by the numba compiler. I then use this list of bit indices to build the slice indices for slices of bits to keep. The final loop copies these slices to an empty output array.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from time import time

def binary_mask(num, mask):
    num_nbits = num.shape[0] #how many bits are in our big num
    mask_bits = np.where(mask)[0] #which bits are we deleting
    mask_n_bits = mask_bits.shape[0] #how many bits are we deleting
    start = np.empty(mask_n_bits + 1, dtype=int) #preallocate array for slice start indexes
    start[0] = 0 #first slice starts at 0
    start[1:] = mask_bits + 1 #subsequent slices start 1 after each True bit in mask
    end = np.empty(mask_n_bits + 1, dtype=int) #preallocate array for slice end indexes
    end[:mask_n_bits] = mask_bits #each slice ends on (but does not include) True bits in the mask
    end[mask_n_bits] = num_nbits + 1 #last slice goes all the way to the end
    out = np.empty(num_nbits - mask_n_bits, dtype=np.uint8) #preallocate return array
    for i in range(mask_n_bits + 1): #for each slice 
        a = start[i] #use local variables to reduce number of lookups
        b = end[i]
        c = a - i
        d = b - i
        out[c:d] = num[a:b] #copy slices
    return out

jit_binary_mask = jit("b1[:](b1[:], b1[:])")(binary_mask) #decorator without syntax sugar

###################### Benchmark ########################

bignum = np.random.randint(0,2,1000000, dtype=bool) # 1 million random bits
bigmask = np.random.randint(0,10,1000000, dtype=np.uint8)==9 #delete about 1 in 10 bits

t = time()
for _ in range(10): #10 cycles of just numpy implementation
    out = binary_mask(bignum, bigmask)
print(f"non-jit: {time()-t} seconds")

t = time()
out = jit_binary_mask(bignum, bigmask) #once ahead of time to compile
compile_and_run = time() - t

t = time()
for _ in range(10): #10 cycles of compiled numpy implementation
    out = jit_binary_mask(bignum, bigmask)
jit_runtime = time()-t
print(f"jit: {jit_runtime} seconds")

print(f"estimated compile_time: {compile_and_run - jit_runtime/10}")
```

In this example, I execute the benchmark on a boolean array of length 1,000,000 a total of 10 times for both the compiled and un-compiled version. On my laptop, the output is:

```
non-jit: 1.865583896636963 seconds
jit: 0.06370806694030762 seconds
estimated compile_time: 0.1652850866317749
```

As you can see with a simple algorithm like this, very significant performance gains can be seen from compilation. (in my case about 20-30x speedup)

Comment: after more testing, the scaling seems to be very linear with both memory and cpu time

Comment: more testing... other answers take several orders of magnitude longer for numbers in the range of 2^1e6 (10's of seconds to minutes)

Comment: This looks promising to increase speed. I'll try it.

 1) The main problem with my current solution is that I need to apply mask to large number of different big integers.

 2) It works much slower in case I have low number of '1' in mask.

Comment: @ZFTurbo This solution should actually be particularly well suited to sparse masks. The for loop is basically just doing a memcpy, so as the mask gets more sparse, there will be fewer calls that copy more at a time each.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this can be done without the use of loops if and only if `M` is a power of 2.

Let's take your example, and modify `M` so that it is a power of 2:

```
N = 0b100011101110 = 2286
M = 0b000000001000 = 8
```

Removing the fourth lowest bit from `N` and shifting the higher bits to the right would result in:

```
N = 0b10001110110 = 1142
```

We achieved this using the following algorithm:

- Begin with `N = 0b100011101110 = 2286`
- Iterate from the most-significant bit to the least-significant bit in `M`.
- If the current bit in `M` is set to 1, then store the lower bits in some variable, `x`:

  - `x = 0b1101110`
- Then, subtract every bit up to and including the current bit in `M` from `N`, so that we end up with the following:

  - `N - (0b10000000 + x) = N - (0b10000000 + 0b1101110) = 0b100011101110 - 0b11101110 = 0b100000000000`
  - This step can also be achieved by *and*-ing the bits with `0`, which may be more efficient.
- Next, we shift the result once to the right:

  - `0b100000000000 >> 1 = 0b10000000000`
- Finally, we add back `x` to the shifted result:

  - `0b10000000000 + x = 0b10000000000 + 0b1101110 = 0b10001101110 = 1142`

There may be a possibility that this can somehow be done without loops, but it would **actually be efficient** if you were to simply iterate over `M` (from the most-significant bit to the least-significant bit) and performed this process on every set bit, as the time complexity would be `O(M.bit_length())`.

I wrote up the code for this algorithm as well, and I believe it's relatively efficient, but I don't have any big binary numbers to test it with:

```
def remove_bits(N, M):
    bit = 2 ** (M.bit_length() - 1)

    while bit != 0:
        if M & bit:
            ones = bit - 1

            # Store lower `bit` bits.
            temp = N & ones

            # Clear lower `bit` bits.
            N &= ~ones

            # Shift once to the right.
            N >>= 1

            # Set stored lower `bit` bits.
            N |= temp

        bit >>= 1

    return N

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 0b100011101110
    M = 0b000010001000

    print(bin(remove_bits(N, M)))
```

Using your example, this returns your result: `0b1000110110`

Comment: It would take O(numbits(M)) bitwise operations, but with millions of digits, those bitwise operations would take O(numbits(N)) time each. The overall runtime would be quadratic in the input size, which may not be viable.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't believe the bitwise operations would be slow, even with millions of digits.  I'd love some data from OP so I can actually test it.

Comment: @JacobG. bitwise operations are not fast in python. It's true they're very fast in x86, but python doesn't use those instructions to their fullest

Comment: @Aaron I'm honestly not surprised, how do you think the algorithm would fare in a language such as C or Java?  Not much would have to be changed.

Comment: @JacobG. I actually wouldn't be surprised if C did very well with it. possibly even Java, as there are some very low level virtual machines (ex: Davlik)

Comment: @Aaron I'll try benchmarking it in Java when I have time, but I don't expect it to outperform yours.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any way to do this in a constant number of calls to the built-in bitwise operators. Python would have to provide something like [`PEXT`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXT.html) for that to be possible.

For literally millions of digits, you may actually get best performance by working in terms of sequences of bits, sacrificing the space advantages of Python ints and the time advantages of bitwise operations in favor of more flexibility in the operations you can perform. I don't know where the break-even point would be:

```
import itertools

bits = bin(N)[2:]
maskbits = bin(M)[2:].zfill(len(bits))
bits = bits.zfill(len(maskbits))

chosenbits = itertools.compress(bits, map('0'.__eq__, maskbits))

result = int(''.join(chosenbits), 2)
```

Comment: @JacobG.: Whoops, forgot that `bin` would truncate leading zeros.